# Дух превратился в Community

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дух-сообщества

На основном сайте сообщение отображается так:

[image: Скриншот с ruSO]

хотя на мете недавно всё было хорошо:

[image: Скриншот]

Кстати, а почему текст разный?

Comment: Проверил учётку Духа, там всё нормально. Значит снова где-то захардкодили строки.

Comment: Нашёл только [`**Поднят на главную страницу** участником $community$ $when$`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/103040400?key=5db278ad81e488c08824460f22d94c4f)

Comment: [Отписался](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288223/339911) об этом на SE.Meta с предложением по фиксу.

Comment: Все эти перетрубации происходят по причине того, что сразу строку в нормальный вид не смогли привести, а в текущем виде её стало невозможно локализовать с учётом особенностей русского сайта.

Comment: Правильный перевод на русский должен быть `**Поднят на главную страницу** [Духом сообщества $diamond$]($communityLink$) $when$`, потому что иначе необходимо прописывать все 6 падежей (и это ещё только на русском, в кое-каких языках их по 12).

Comment: @VladD перевод не может использовать переменные, которых нет в исходной строке. Поэтому сначала исходная строка должна принять соответствующий вид.

Comment: @alexolut: Именно так!

Comment: @VladD я думаю, теперь надо ждать понедельника как минимум.

Comment: @alexolut: Кстати, всё это затрагивает и перевод на португальский. Интересно, как они к этому относятся?

Comment: @VladD помимо португальского есть ещё и испанский. Можно спросить у них на Мете :) Вы знаете португальский?

Comment: @alexolut: Не-а, к сожалению не знаю :)

Comment: Теоретически, ошибка должна быть устранена. Проверяйте!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да. Я ещё вчера видел.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как именно завершено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На текущий момент ошибку исправили:

> [image: главдух]

но с [решением](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288338/339911) я не согласен, т.к. нет возможности менять падеж Духа. Может быть мы вместе убедим [Oded ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) в ошибочности такого фикса?

Comment: Не думаю, что это реально. Строка задумана, как способная содержать имя любого участника. Предлагаете написать движок, занимающийся склонениями произвольных ников? Или захардкодить ссылку на участника прямо во все сообщение, т. к. кроме него никто не может это сделать (кстати, так ли это?)?

Comment: @D-side там конкретная переменная `$community$`. Никаких любых участников нет!

Comment: Ок. Убедительно. Хотя по контексту он всё равно похож на ссылку участника в общем случае и я бы скорее целился в переформулировку этой строки, а-ля "Дух сообщества **поднял вопрос на главную страницу** 4 часа назад". Согнутся ли так же хорошо другие языки... хороший вопрос.

Comment: `**Поднят на главную страницу** [Духом Сообщества](/users/-1) $when$` - **Поднят на главную страницу** [Духом Сообщества](/users/-1) $when$ - почему так не сделать?

Comment: @Qwertiy почитайте чат, начиная [отсюда](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34233440#34233440).

Comment: @alexolut, плохой вариант. Акцент должен быть на том, что вопрос поднят, а не то, что Дух что-то сделал, поэтому ставить Духа в начало предложения не надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy я где-то предлагал поставить Духа в начало предложения?

Comment: @alexolut, "хардкодь уже"?

Comment: @Qwertiy штоа?!